# ecommerce options for 5-6 products

Tags: web-development, ecommerce

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Ecommerce Script Should I Use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/30150/which-ecommerce-script-should-i-use)

We're looking to develop a simple e-commerce solution to sell 5-6 products.

We'd rather not have to use PayPal's buttons (buy it now!) if there's an existing alternative, but would also for budget/time constraints don't want to roll our own.

Are there any small, basic ecommerce solutions available that would allow this? I did look at [Foxy Cart](http://www.foxycart.com/) but the monthly fee was a bit of a turn off. (I must sound extremely fussy I'm aware!)

Something like Zen would just be overkill for our needs.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Is [Shopify](http://www.shopify.com/) an option? Or [Etsy](http://www.etsy.com)?

Answer (score 1):

I like [Prestashop](http://www.prestashop.com/) and so do my customers. It is easy to use, looks clean, uses AJax for the admin backend and isn't stuffed full of complicated options that confuse.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Ubercart http://www.ubercart.org/

Answer (score 0):

[Magentocommerce](http://www.magentocommerce.com/) seems to be "to much"? Maybe Wordpress with a E-Commerce Plugin?

Answer (score 0):

[Wazala](http://www.wazala.com/)'s lowest pricing tier is ten bucks a month.

If a monthly fee is completely unacceptable(come on), they also have a free plan which is limited to 5 items and has a couple other restrictions that may or may not be important to you.